Improve efficiency of sum of triplets with wrap around (conway's game of life)
I'm trying to implement Conway's game of life in C. This is the method I'm using in order to compute the number of neighbours around each cell.
This part of the code appears to be quite slow (73,5% of the total time of execution) 4.16s:
void generar_sumas_total(CELL_TYPE *tablero, CELL_TYPE *tab_sum, INDEX_TYPE Y, INDEX_TYPE X) {
    INDEX_TYPE i, j;

    #pragma omp parallel for schedule(static)
    for (i = 0; i < Y; i++) {
        INDEX_TYPE top_row = (i == 0) ? Y - 1 : i - 1;
        INDEX_TYPE bottom_row = (i == Y - 1) ? 0 : i + 1;

        for (j = 0; j < X; j++) {
            INDEX_TYPE left_col = (j == 0) ? X - 1 : j - 1;
            INDEX_TYPE right_col = (j == X - 1) ? 0 : j + 1;

            CELL_TYPE sum = tablero[top_row * X + left_col] + 
                            tablero[top_row * X + j] + 
                            tablero[top_row * X + right_col] + 
                            tablero[i * X + left_col] + 
                            tablero[i * X + j] + 
                            tablero[i * X + right_col] + 
                            tablero[bottom_row * X + left_col] + 
                            tablero[bottom_row * X + j] + 
                            tablero[bottom_row * X + right_col];

            tab_sum[i * X + j] = sum;
        }
    }
}

Previous to this combined method, I had these two separate methods that were more efficient (22%+3,59%), 2.95s:
void generar_sumasV ( CELL_TYPE *tabIn, CELL_TYPE *tabSum, INDEX_TYPE Y, INDEX_TYPE X )
{
    INDEX_TYPE i, j;
    INDEX_TYPE lastRowIdx = (Y - 1) * X;

    // precompute first and last rows
    CELL_TYPE firstRowSum, lastRowSum;

    #pragma omp parallel for private(j)
    for (j = 0; j < X; j++) {
        CELL_TYPE t0 = tabIn[j];
        CELL_TYPE t1 = tabIn[lastRowIdx + j];
        CELL_TYPE t2 = tabIn[X + j];
        CELL_TYPE t3 = tabIn[lastRowIdx - X + j];

        firstRowSum = t0 + t1 + t2;
        lastRowSum = t0 + t1 + t3;

        tabSum[j] = firstRowSum; // First row
        tabSum[lastRowIdx + j] = lastRowSum; // Last row
    }

    INDEX_TYPE currentRowIdx, prevRowIdx, nextRowIdx;
    #pragma omp parallel for private(j)
    for (i = 1; i < Y - 1; i++) {
        prevRowIdx = (i - 1) * X;
        currentRowIdx = i * X;
        nextRowIdx = (i + 1) * X;
        for (j = 0; j < X; j++) {
            tabSum[currentRowIdx + j] = tabIn[prevRowIdx + j] + tabIn[currentRowIdx + j] + tabIn[nextRowIdx + j];
        }
    }
}


void generar_sumasH(CELL_TYPE *tabSumV, CELL_TYPE *tabSumH, INDEX_TYPE Y, INDEX_TYPE X)
{
    INDEX_TYPE i, j, fX = 0;

    // Precompute the first and last columns outside the main loop
    for (i = 0; i < Y; i++)  // For all rows of board
    {
        // Calculate for the first column in the row
        CELL_TYPE left = tabSumV[fX + X - 1];  // wrap-around left
        CELL_TYPE middle = tabSumV[fX];
        CELL_TYPE right = tabSumV[fX + 1];
        tabSumH[fX] = left + middle + right;

        // Calculate for the middle columns in the row
        for (j = 1; j < X - 1; j++)
        {
            left = tabSumV[fX + j - 1];
            middle = tabSumV[fX + j];
            right = tabSumV[fX + j + 1];
            tabSumH[fX + j] = left + middle + right;
        }

        // Calculate for the last column in the row
        left = tabSumV[fX + X - 2];
        middle = tabSumV[fX + X - 1];
        right = tabSumV[fX];  // wrap-around right
        tabSumH[fX + X - 1] = left + middle + right;

        fX += X;  // NEXT ROW
    }
}

called consecutively as so:
    generar_sumasV    ( tablero, tab_sum1, Y, X );
    generar_sumasH    ( tab_sum1, tab_sum2, Y, X );


In this case the bottleneck (other than omp) seems to be actualizar_tabler_con_cambios, which has the following code:
void actualizar_tablero_con_cambios(CELL_TYPE *tabIn, CELL_TYPE *tabSum, INDEX_TYPE Y, INDEX_TYPE X, int *cambios)
{
    INDEX_TYPE i, j;
    CELL_TYPE old, vecinos;
    int local_changes = 0;

    #pragma omp parallel for private(j, old, vecinos) reduction(+:local_changes)
    for (i = 0; i < Y; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < X; j++)
        {
            old = tabIn[i * X + j];
            vecinos = tabSum[i * X + j];
            CELL_TYPE new_value = (old & (vecinos == 4)) | (vecinos == 3);
            tabIn[i * X + j] = new_value;
            local_changes += (old != new_value);
        }
    }
    *cambios = local_changes;
}

I don't know which direction I should take from this two options in order to achieve as much performance as possible - I thought combining the two sum methods into one would increase the performance, but it's clearly not working.
My question is, which other solutions can I use that are more efficient than both of these options, or how can I modify my current code to make it faster.
I know the code can be sped up by at least 3x.

You are measuring optimized builds, right?

@TedLyngmo yes, I'm compiling with gcc -Ofast -fopenmp -march=native CH2.c -o CH2

This may be better suited to https://codereview.stackexchange.com.

You might get some efficiency if instead of summing the neighbours of every cell, you first make a block clearance of the count map, and add 1 to the count of each neighbour only for occupied cells. Especially when the population is sparse, as it usually is. You can also get efficiency by working with alternating buffers, instead of copying the output back to the input (although you didn't show that).

No @Chris, it doesn't look like a Code Review question.  It's only asking about code performance, not about any other aspect of the code, and it's not even complete.

Before pushing into OMP - and depending on you machine - consider using SSE/AVX - on any modren machine you can get 256 or 512 operation - assuming CELLTYPE is byte - that translate to 32 or 64 bytes. You can get a lot of mileage - if you focus on this path. Use vec-report to see if the optimizer was able to parallelize , or why not.
You can go into OMP later, if you need more performance.

Maybe try rewriting those conditionals as branchless?  INDEX_TYPE top_row = (i == 0) ? Y - 1 : i - 1; => INDEX_TYPE top_row = (i + !i * y) - 1;

The compiler probably already this for you but I would introduce some variables instead of those repeated calculations: CELL_TYPE *tmp = tablero + top_row * X; ... sum = tmp[left_col] + tmp[j] + ... and maybe wrap that 3 pattern sum in a macro.

I know very little about omp but if different threads touch the same memory then it would have synchronize (i.e. serialize) for correct results. Either pass copies, or make the threads work on non-overlapping segments of the table and tell omp that.

Why do you assign the result to the temporary sum when you need tab_sum[...]?  I am curious.

Isn't the inner loop doing row instead of column access?  Swap the two loops so the inner loop does column changes which has better locality.

How do you calculate the efficiency results?  IMHO you don't need to compute all cells around a given one.  As you can stop as soon as you have 4 cells filled, you know the final result, the cell is about to die.  Also you can reduce your search to the cells that have one life around, as cells that don't have a cell alive around are never going to produce a new life.  This will reduce drastically your search to the alive cells plus the cells surrounding them.  You can put the living cells in a list, traverse it, searching for all nonvisited cells that surround them.
